# MYSQL Select, get rid of column name

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have returned a column of my mysql server(nevermind that they're all the same number...this is jut for testing purposes)

I want all of the numbers in an array...JUST the numbers, not the name of the column 'Northatt'.

below is the code and the result. I've already tried result.northatt, it only returns the first number.

```
client.query('SELECT Northatt FROM archive', function(err,result){
                console.log(result);
        });

Result:  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 },
  { Northatt: 23 }..etc.
```

I just want the numbers.

Comment: you have just Northatt in your column ? no other strings ?

Comment: `result.map(function(a){ return a.Northatt; });`?

Comment: It looks like there are no other strings in the result. I will give your suggestion a try.

Comment: There may be a method built-in to get the data in the format you want, but I don't know node.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`result` is an array of objects.  If you just want (the) one value from each of the objects, use `.map`.

```
var Northatt = result.map(function(a){
    return a.Northatt;
});
```

`Northatt` will be an array of just the values.